# c# 2008 sample windows application

Tags: c#, winforms

I want to create windows application in c# 2008.

The problem is I don't have enough knowledge about this.

Can anybody give me some links to study about writing codes in C# specially for windows application?

I would like to read tutorials about windows applications.

Comment: You might get better responses if you post questions about specific problems you're experiencing

Comment: Google, MSDN, book store, college classes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MSDN will help You. :)
[Getting Started with Visual C# (2008)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/a72418yk.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest buying yourself a book.

I purchased the first edition of [Learning C#](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596102098/), and found it to a brilliant introduction to the language.

Answer (score 0):

Are you really sure you want to be a programmer?

Answer (score 0):

- http://www.csharpfriends.com/
- http://www.csharp-station.com/
- http://www.csharphelp.com/
- http://www.blackwasp.co.uk/